# Append line break to current line (opposite of `J`)

Tags: normal-mode

Is it possible to append a line break to the current line in normal-mode? Basically the opposite of what `J` does.

Answer (score 2):

I think the closest to what you want would be to replace the character under your cursor by a new line which you can do with <kbd>r</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>.

You could also use these mappings:

```
nnoremap <Leader>o o<Esc>0"_D
nnoremap <Leader>O O<Esc>0"_D
```

They will add a new line under or above the current line without changing your registers.

Comment: Nice trick! Never thought about doing it that way.